# Incorrect row returned in .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to run VBA in Excel from Access. The user enters data into a table in Access, and the table is imported into a table in Excel ("TableData1") where various charts and pivot tables reside. When the Excel spreadsheet is opened the tables are refreshed with the most current data from the database. The table is then filtered to "last month".

However, when I try to find the last row where the data is entered on my filtered table, Excel returns the last row upon opening the spreadsheet, not the last row after the refresh and filter has taken place. I'm not sure if I am missing a step here, or if I coded something wrong. I've tried a few different "last row" methods and all of them are returning the wrong row number.

There are several years of data in this table, and I'm filtering to last month (currently September 2017). I've included 2 of the many codes I've attempted for `summaryrow` below (one commented out). Both return the old line before the refresh (1072) when it should be 1089. Keep in mind the refresh and filter does work and it shows the correct data on the table.

```
Function RunMyReport()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

Dim wsTable As Worksheet

Dim SummaryRow As Long

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\MySpreadsheet.xlsx")
    End With


    Set wsTable = xlWB.Worksheets("Table") 'The name of the worksheet I am working in

    With wsTable
        .Activate
        .ListObjects("TableData1").Refresh 'Refresh for the most recent data
        .ListObjects("TableData1").Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:= _
            xlFilterDynamic 'Filters the data table to last month
        SummaryRow = Cells.Find(What:=” * ”, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        'SummaryRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'find the Summary row

    End With
    MsgBox SummaryRow

End Function
```

Comment: `Find()` does not locate values on rows which are filtered out.  Likewise, `End(xlUp)` will skip right over any rows at the end of the dataset which have been hidden using a filter.  Note: hiding rows manually (not using a filter) doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: You don't seem to have defined the variable `” * ”` anywhere.  Did you mean that to be the string literal `" * "`?

Comment: @YowE3K -  Ignoring the "smart quotes" and the spaces, that just means "find any value"

Comment: So are you saying I should manually filter out the old dates?

Comment: Do you want to last row *including* any filtered rows?

Comment: I just need the last row (which is the total row) to copy and paste into another worksheet

Comment: `.ListObjects("TableData1").DataBodyRange` will give you the full set of data for the table (including any filtered rows), so you could take the last row of that range.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hmm - I just put some dummy data in a worksheet and then tried various `Find`s - using `” * ”` returned row 5 (which happened to include a `=NOW()` formula I had been using for something), using `""` returned row 13 (one row after the last populated cell), and using `"*"` correctly returned row 12.  I wonder why `” * ”` and `""` are different?  (Oh, and `" * "` crashed because there were no cells with a leading and trailing space.)

Comment: One means "find something" and the other means "find nothing" ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Doh!! I was thinking that `” * ”` was a variable, but it isn't.  It's a variable multiplied by itself, so `” * ”` will be equal to `0` if the variable `”` isn't assigned a value.  I had been thinking that `” * ”` was one variable name with a default value of `""`

Comment: Anyway, getting back to the question itself, you are doing your `Find` within `Cells`.  An unqualified `Cells` defaults to the active sheet in the active workbook in the active (or maybe default, i.e. early bound?) application, but your workbook and worksheet are in a different application.  Qualify it and use `.Cells.Find`.  (And stop searching for `0` - i.e. change `” * ”` to `"*"`.)

Comment: SummaryRow = wsTable.Cells.Find(What:=("*"), SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
Gives me the same result. When I try to remove the spaces Access re-adds them automatically so I tried parentheses.

Comment: Nevermind it worked after I removed the parentheses